# find active records from database and compare two dates

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
function getactiveusers() {
    $cur_date = date('d M Y');
    $this->db->where('expiration >', $cur_date);
    $query = $this->db->get('userinfo');
    return $query->result(); }
```

This is my query to find all active users but it returns all users. Can anyone help me to filter records.

Comment: What is the data type of the `expiration` field? Because if it is date, then you would be better off formatting the date as 'YYYY-MM-DD'. If it is char/varchar, then you should convert it to date.

Comment: Date format :- date('d M Y')
Database :- MySQL
Tech :- Codeigniter 3

Comment: and field type is :- text

Comment: Then you should convert it to date.